# Programmatically generating 3D models that can be imported into blender

Tags: c++, 3d, modeling, blender

I'm looking for the simplest/easiest way to generate **3D mesh** models programmatically.

I'm working on C++ and need to import the 3D models into Blender, so there should be a way to export them into a standard file format. The models I need are relatively simple, textureless, no materials, no shading, just geometry.

**What kind of tools/libraries are there to achieve this?** The easiest method the better (I'm actually quite fluent on c++ but don't really want to spend much time learning a complex API)

Any reference to documentation or tutorial would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: There's currently [a new SE in beta](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) that might accept such questions in the future. Sorry it's off-topic at SO. I think it's a good question in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate 3d meshed programatically in any language and save then as OBJ [Wavefront OBJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). This is the easiest I can think of. OBJ can be imported to virtually anything 3d related blender, 3ds, maya, mari, zbrush, mubdox etc.